How to split typescript props that were intersected together to pass through to two different children components?
I have two children components, each with complex and non-trivial props:
interface Child1Props = { foo: string; bar: string, baz: string  }
interface Child2Props = { foo: string, qux: string, quux: string }

const Child1 = (props: Child1Props) => {};
const Child2 = (props: Child2Props) => {};

And I have a parent component that intersects both children props and renders both children. Is there a way to use the spread operator to pass down the appropriate props for each child without explicitly writing them out? As far as I'm aware, I can only use the spread operator on one child and I'll have to explicitly call each prop on the other which is what I'm hoping to avoid:
const Parent = ({foo, bar, baz, ..rest): Child1Props & Child2Props) => (
   <Child1 foo={foo} bar={bar} baz={baz} >
     <Child2 foo={foo} {...rest} />
   </Child1>
)

I would love for the Parent component to be completely unaware of the children props and do something like the following non-working/incomplete example.
const Parent = (props: Child1Props & Child2Props) => (
   <Child1 {...child1Props} >
     <Child2 {...child2Props} />
   </Child1>
)

Is there a trick to make this possible? Basically I want to un-intersect the props after intersecting them.

Please [edit] this to be a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. (no pseudocode, etc). If I try to do that I get the version at this playground link and there's no problem. Your components don't care about extra properties (and given your example, they don't care about any properties). TypeScript assumes that extra properties can be safely ignored, so if you have an actual problem with passing such properties, you should show us with a [mre] where it really matters.
